# Deployed Silverlight app doesn't show

Tags: .net, silverlight, deployment

I have a Silverlight application I built with the create webpage activated.
When I click myapp.aspx in the myapp.WEB folder everything works fine.
But after I uploaded the whole myapp.WEB folder to my webhotel and runs the page nothing shows on the screen. Only white.
If I right-click, it says Silverlight.

How to debug?

It's a Silverlight 4 app and the aspx page is .NET 3.5

The BODY looks like this:

```
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
      <param name="source" value="ClientBin/AnimationEx.xap"/>
      <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
      <param name="background" value="white" />
      <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50826.0" />

      <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
      <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50826.0" style="text-decoration:none">
          <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
      </a>
    </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post your code where you're declaring the Silverlight object.

Comment: There are a lot of reasons why it could go wrong. Does the `ClientBin` folder exist in the right location? Is the xap file in the `ClientBin` folder? Have you uploaded all the dependent zip files?

Comment: Yes the ClientBin has the AnimationEx.xap.

Zip files?
i thhought every thing got compiled together?

Comment: I think you have to change some settings in IIS for it to understand how to host Silverlight.  Maybe add mime types...

Comment: What does the application do? Are you trying to connect to a database on another server? If that's the case then you'll need to setup the cross domain policy on the webservice to allow the web server access.

Comment: No. Its a simple "game".
i´ll try to ask at my web hotel.
Cheers!

Comment: Solution: Add mime typ application/x-silverlight-2 for .xap at the web hotel!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you're using .net version 3.5, but the BODY has

```
<param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50826.0" />
```

I believe you have to have IIS setup with the target version being 4.0 in order to make that work. That would be under the settings for your site.